# JQuery hover effect problem

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseout

I have created a simple JQuery script with hovering effect on some links. The script works fine as you can see here : [Test Sample](http://www.pdfindexgenerator.com/test_area/jquery_hover_effect) ... (Please test it on any browser other than IE)

But if i hover **fast** on the links, you will notice the image icons do not disappear as required. I have tried everything to fix this but i can't find a suitable solution.

The question now: ***How can i be sure the mouseOut hover effect is applied after the mouseOver hover effect is completely done ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the `stop()` to the elements that have been animated.
Try this:

```
function hide_frame() {
   var hoveredLang = $(this).parent();              
   hoveredLang
      .find('.language-name').stop(true, true)
      .find('.download-img').stop(true, true)
      .find('.info-img').stop(true, true);
   //eccetera...
```

Comment: Yes ... I've got that, it's now working fine.
I should apply the stop() to every effect per element.
Thanks a lot Alex & o.k.w :)

Answer (score 2):

Becuase your animation effect has a duration to completion, you need to handle cases where hover/unhover happen during the animation.

I use JQuery's `stop` function (http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop)

Eg.

$("selector").stop(true,true).youreffect(.....);

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the help Eg.

I did it as you mentioned, i wrote in the unhover event :
$(this).stop(true, true);

But nothing is changed ... You can check it in the sample online, i have updated it. But your idea is right ... The problem is because i unhover so fast before the duration of the hover effect completes.

Any other suggestion ?